# NUnit CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected,actual) vs Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual))

Tags: c#, linq, collections, nunit, assertions

I have some objects that get placed into a queue. All of the objects in the queue implement the same base interface, which also requires that they implement IEquatable<>.

I want to verify that the correct objects are being placed in the queue in the correct order.

When I write a test that makes the assertion `CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected,actual)`, the test fails, stating that, while the queue is the expected length, it differs at index 0.

However, when I write the test assertion as `Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual))`, the test passes.

It seems to me that these two assertions should be the same, but apparently they are quite different.

NUnit's website isn't very detailed about the collection assert methods, and the Linq documentation, while more detailed, doesn't really help without being able to compare to what NUnit is doing with the collection assert method.

How do these two assertions differ?

**Edit - Adding detail**

Here is the code under test as well as the two tests that I would expect to have the same result.

```
public enum ArgumentTypeEnum
{
    SpiceworksDbName,
    DestinationDbName,
    DestinationServerName
}

public interface IArgument : IEquatable<IArgument>
{
}

public interface ICommandArgument : IArgument
{
    ArgumentTypeEnum ArgumentType { get; }
}

internal interface IValueArgument : IArgument
{
    String ArgumentValue { get; }
}

public class CommandArgument : ICommandArgument
{
    public CommandArgument(ArgumentTypeEnum argumentType) {
        ArgumentType = argumentType;
    }

    public ArgumentTypeEnum ArgumentType { get; private set; }

    public bool Equals(IArgument other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var otherAsCommandArg = other as CommandArgument;
        if (otherAsCommandArg == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return ArgumentType == otherAsCommandArg.ArgumentType;
    }
}

public class ValueArgument : IValueArgument
{
    public ValueArgument(String argumentValue)
    {
        ArgumentValue = argumentValue;
    }

    public string ArgumentValue { get; private set; }

    public bool Equals(IArgument other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var otherAsValueArg = other as ValueArgument;
        if (otherAsValueArg == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return ArgumentValue == otherAsValueArg.ArgumentValue;
    }
}

public class Tokenizer
{
     public Queue<IArgument> TokenizeArguments(string[] args) {
        var tokenQueue = new Queue<IArgument>();
        args.ToList().ForEach((arg) => {
                if (arg.StartsWith("-"))
                {
                    switch (arg)
                    {
                        case "-sd":
                            tokenQueue.Enqueue(new CommandArgument(ArgumentTypeEnum.SpiceworksDbName));
                            break;
                        case "-dd":
                            tokenQueue.Enqueue(new CommandArgument(ArgumentTypeEnum.DestinationDbName));
                            break;
                        case "-ds":
                            tokenQueue.Enqueue(new CommandArgument(ArgumentTypeEnum.DestinationServerName));
                            break;
                        default:
                            tokenQueue.Enqueue(new ValueArgument(arg));
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    tokenQueue.Enqueue(new ValueArgument(arg));
                }
            });
        return tokenQueue;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TokenizerSpecs
{
    ///Passes
    [Test] 
    public void Tokenizer_MultipleCommandsAndValues_TokenizesAsExpected1() {
        var args = new[]
        {
            "-sd", @"\\some\Directory\foo.db", "-dd", "some database name", "-ds", "Server.name", "somerandomarg",
            "-unreconized"
        };
        var t = new Tokenizer();
        var actualResult = t.TokenizeArguments(args);

        var expectedResult = new Queue<IArgument>();
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new CommandArgument(ArgumentTypeEnum.SpiceworksDbName));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new ValueArgument(@"\\some\Directory\foo.db"));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new CommandArgument(ArgumentTypeEnum.DestinationDbName));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new ValueArgument("some database name"));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new CommandArgument(ArgumentTypeEnum.DestinationServerName));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new ValueArgument("Server.name"));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new ValueArgument("somerandomarg"));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new ValueArgument("-unreconized"));

        Assert.IsTrue(expectedResult.SequenceEqual(actualResult));
    }

    ///Fails
    [Test]
    public void Tokenizer_MultipleCommandsAndValues_TokenizesAsExpected2()
    {
        var args = new[]
        {
            "-sd", @"\\some\Directory\foo.db", "-dd", "some database name", "-ds", "Server.name", "somerandomarg",
            "-unreconized"
        };
        var t = new Tokenizer();
        var actualResult = t.TokenizeArguments(args);

        var expectedResult = new Queue<IArgument>();
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new CommandArgument(ArgumentTypeEnum.SpiceworksDbName));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new ValueArgument(@"\\some\Directory\foo.db"));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new CommandArgument(ArgumentTypeEnum.DestinationDbName));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new ValueArgument("some database name"));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new CommandArgument(ArgumentTypeEnum.DestinationServerName));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new ValueArgument("Server.name"));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new ValueArgument("somerandomarg"));
        expectedResult.Enqueue(new ValueArgument("-unreconized"));

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick test with two `Queue`s containing `IEquatable<>`s doesn't confirm your finding: both methods pass or fail in unison. Maybe you should show some more details.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll add some more detail shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken a look at NUnit's source code and it seems you've got a bug here. The comparison is done by `NUnitEqualityComparer.EnumerablesEqual` which subsequently compares each element by `NUnitEqualityComparer.ObjectsEqual`. We can do simple test using this object:

```
var n = new NUnitEqualityComparer();
var tolerance = Tolerance.Zero;
var equal = n.AreEqual(new CommandArgument(ArgumentTypeEnum.SpiceworksDbName),
                       new CommandArgument(ArgumentTypeEnum.SpiceworksDbName),
                       ref tolerance);
```

This test returns `false`!

Somehow, `ObjectsEqual` doesn't end up in the object's `Equals` method. It would require debugging against the source code to find out why, but this test sufficiently proves that a bug is involved.

Comment: Very interesting! So the method I proposed (using SequenceEqual) is the safe way to go for now?

Any idea what the limits of this bug might be? Do you think the issue affects all comparisons of all objects that implement IEquatable?

Comment: Seems so. Knowing this, I'd certainly use `SequenceEqual`. I can't fathom the impact of this bug but it looks quite serious.

Comment: I submitted an issue on the NUnit Github page in response to this.